# FBSDKLoginManager loginBehavior SDK v4.14.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

When facebook app install in our iPhone redirect to login process from App and fallback case redirect to safari. But current case application all time redirect to safari.

I have use SDK v4.14.0

```
FBSDKLoginManager* loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
loginManager.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;
NSString *sdkVersion =[FBSDKSettings sdkVersion];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[ @"email" ] fromViewController:nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
}];
```

and LSApplicationQueriesSchemes {fbapi/fb-messenger-api/fbauth2/fbshareextension}

Please suggest the solution thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is safari ? Safari browser is different than SFSafariViewCOntroller.

Comment: Yes,both case we are not required @TejaNandamuri

Comment: try to check this post i think its the sam problem hope it help you !! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971727/facebook-native-login-is-not-opening-facebook-app-even-if-its-installed-in-devi)